# Django Generic Sitemap and Appending slashes

Tags: django, sitemap

Google is complaining of a 301 redirect for URLs in my sitemap.

I'm using GenericSitemap, and my APPEND_SLASH setting is defaulted (on).  My URLs therefore redirect so they end with a slash, which is how I like it.  However the default django sitemap (django.contrib.sitemaps) doesn't put these trailing slashes on the urls it generates.

I think I've followed all the docs correctly and can't find any answers on google - any ideas?

Comment: Any ideas? Am I supposed to override get_absolute_url for all my models to cater for the slash?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the [source code of django.contrib.sitemaps](https://bitbucket.org/django/django/src/e752cdf831a7/django/contrib/sitemaps/__init__.py#cl-55), `get_absolute_url` is used for building the sitemap, so the best thing would probably be starting to convert your urls model by model.  However, if it causes you too much problems, you can meanwhile subclass GenericSiteMap to add slashes to all urls without a trailing slash:

```
class SlashedGenericSitemap(GenericSitemap):
    def location(self, obj):
        url = obj.get_absolute_url()
        return url if len(url)>0 and url[-1]=='/' else url + '/'
```

And of course, use it instead of GenericSiteMap.

Comment: Thanks for this, although as Append_slash is defaulted to on, I would have thought dozens of people would have had the same difficulty/behaviour as I have, yet I seem to be the only one...?

Comment: `APPEND_SLASH = True` is actually creating the redirects.  If it was off (not recommended), you might have noticed it before.  Maybe others did not notice yet they have "redirect problems"...

Comment: Thanks @Udi I'll probably go with the subclassed sitemap, but I'm going to leave the question and bounty open for a couple of days to see if anyone else has any input / best practices